# What are the metabolic concerns associated with hard water?

Tags: metabolism, human-physiology, ph

If humans can maintain a consistent blood pH, then what problems does alkalized water cause us?

Why is it recommended that we filter and boil hard water? Is the issue that hard water can affect the pH of our blood?

Comment: Could you add where you have gotten this advice? I have lived in many regions with pretty hard water, and never came across it. The only reason I could envisage is to improve the water's taste...

Comment: @Gerhard I don't remember, it is the conventional wisdom.

Comment: It might help mentioning where you are from, if you say that it's "conventional wisdom" :)

Comment: @Gerhard it isn't matter, filters are sold all over the world.

Comment: I don't know this area, but found a recent review http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24049611 on epidemiological studies on hard water. It seems there are no conclusive data showing a health risk. Water hardness will definitely *not* affect your blood pH, which is carefully regulated by buffering systems. I think the reason most people install water softeners is because higher salt content can in the long run damage pipes, valves, dishwashers etc.

Comment: @RS: no problem if you would like to keep your location a secret. It's just that I had never heard of such a claim neither in the south of Germany nor in England and was curious - and thought that there might be something more behind the recommendation than just the hardness of the water, which might depend on your location. And yes, water filters are on sale here, too, but exclusively to improve the taste of tea and coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there is no evidence shows hard water can cause any healthy problem.

Previously people were concerned about the high mineral content, such as calcium and magnesium, may cause disease such like cardiovascular disease.

But from the report World Health Organization published in 2003 [Hardness in Drinking-water](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/en/hardness.pdf), it says "Although a number of epidemiological studies have shown a statistically significant inverse relationship between the hardness of drinking-water and cardiovascular disease, the available data are inadequate to permit the conclusion that the association is causal. No health-based guideline value for water hardness is proposed."

And the United States National Research Council thinks hard water can supply the calcium and magnesium ions that dietary need. [Hard Water Hardness Calcium Magnesium Water Corrosion Mineral Scale](http://www.water-research.net/index.php/water-treatment/tools/hard-water-hardness)

And at the same time, I have to say the filters cannot directly work for hard water because ions cannot be isolate by filter. We can filter the precipitation after boil the water. Boiled water is better because tap water may contain microbes in some country, that will be harm for our health. And also you don't want to feel some "precipitation" while you drinking water. That's it.

For my personal view, I prefer soft water because it tastes a little bit sweet.

Comment: Ions can be isolated and removed by filters.  That's the exact premise of reverse osmosis for water purification. They don't work as well for hard water over time because scale can build up on the filter and drop it's efficiency faster than expected.